# solution verification: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges $\implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

I am new to real analysis, and I have trouble understanding the algebraic manipulation we can do with infinite sums.

Problem:

Let $a_n\geq 0$ for all $n\in N$. Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges  then so does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$.

My proof:

\begin{equation}
\infty>2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n > a_1 + 2a_2+2a_3+2a_4+\cdots=(a_1+a_2)+(a_2+a_3)+\cdots >2\sqrt{a_1a_2}+2\sqrt{a_2a_3}+\cdots =2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}
\end{equation}

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Thank you :) It is so complicated with the brackets and all that jazz

Comment: Essentially the same proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/321172/42969

Comment: why is the strict inequality correct? What if $a_i = 0$ for all $i$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{equation}
\infty>2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \color{red}{\overset{*}{>}} a_1 + 2a_2+2a_3+2a_4+\cdots=(a_1+a_2)+(a_2+a_3)+\cdots \color{red}{\overset{*}{>}}2\sqrt{a_1a_2}+2\sqrt{a_2a_3}+\cdots =2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}
\end{equation}

As pointed out in the comments, the inequalities at $\color{red}{*}$ are not strict when $a_i = 0\ \forall\ i\in\mathbb{N}.$ Otherwise your proof is fine.

The same structure of your proof can be used to show that, for example,

$\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n\ $ converges $\implies \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\max\{a_n, a_{n+1} \}$ converges.

Comment: @metamorphy - well spotted. I missed that!